# Excel Powershell script to filter data between two date range

Tags: excel, powershell

I am new to powershell scripting and I have 300 rows of data in my excel after applying filters on many columns and now my excel sheet has a column for date, now i have to put filter on date to fetch record which has dates between two date range. 
For example: 
End date : today
Start date: today - 7 days

(basically i need to filter last week data only using powershell script on my excel file)

Comment: Well what have you tried so far?
You should take a look at `Import-Csv` and `[timespan]`.

Comment: Thanks @Paxz for pitching in, as i said am new to this i learned so far to find todays date we have the option Get-Date and to do subtract we can do (Get-Date).addDays(-7). But how to apply this two date on my excel filter???

Comment: Please offer a [mcve] so we understand the question better.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$CutoffDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)

$Data = Import-CSV "X:\EXAMPLE.csv" | Where-Object {$_.Date -as [datetime] -lt $CutoffDate}
```

Comment: Just to add, you can also do this as oneliner: `$Data = Import-CSV "X:\EXAMPLE.csv" | Where-Object {$_.Date -as [datetime] -lt $((Get-Date).AddDays(-7))}`

Comment: I have a .xlsx file not an csv file.. and also my excel sheet has dates in many columns for example, column C, E and G has dates and i need to apply date filter only on column "C", how your code will work here?

Comment: Maybe if you post some example code of your .xlsx or your script the community could help in better way

Comment: @Selvakumar Don't put essential information solely into comments; [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51552380/edit) your question to contain this.

Answer (score 0):

so this is want i did finally,
day1 to day5 is the date range i required so assigned each dates to the variables and then apply those into xlFilterValues and then apply it into Selection autofilter.

$xlFilterValues = @($day1, $day2, $day3, $day4, $day5) "\n"
$xl.Selection.AutoFilter(37,$xlFilterValues,7)